# VBA collections defined as static type possible?

Tags: vba, collections, outlook, static

Is it possible to define static collections in VBA macro programming for Outlook?

```
Sub mySub()

    Static myCollection As VBA.Collection

    Set myCollection = New VBA.Collection

        myCollection.Add "entry1"

        myCollection.Add "entry2"

        myCollection.Add "entry3"

End Sub
```

Such that myCollection does not have to be redefined everytime the macro mySub() is triggered.

Comment: I have used static dictionary objects in several circumstances. The benefits are pretty evident vs. late binding. However, I still clear the dictionary object with .RemoveAll before each subsequent use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Static` variable in VBA, will retain its value between calls. Normally, a variable that goes out of scope and isn't referenced anywhere else, gets destroyed; `Static` changes the *declaration* of the variable.

It doesn't change what this instruction does *unconditionally*:

```
Set myCollection = New VBA.Collection
```

Whatever reference the previous run was holding, we're overwriting it *every time*, undoing what `Static` is supposed to buy us.

You would have had the same problem regardless of the type of the variable involved: the issue isn't with the type, it's with the *unconditionality* of the `Set` instruction.

Make it conditional:

```
Static myCollection As VBA.Collection
If myCollection Is Nothing Then
    Set myCollection = New VBA.Collection
End If
```

And now `myCollection` will only be `Nothing` on the first call; subsequent runs will have the `myCollection` reference persisted between calls.

Pretty much what you get with a module-level variable:

```
Option Explicit
Private myCollection As VBA.Collection

Public Sub TestModuleVariable()
    If myCollection Is Nothing Then
        Set myCollection = New VBA.Collection
    End If
    With myCollection
        .Add "entry" & .Count + 1
        Debug.Print .Count
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub TestStaticVariable()
    Static items As VBA.Collection
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Set items = New VBA.Collection
    End If
    With items
        .Add "entry" & .Count + 1
        Debug.Print .Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Which one to use depends on what the rest of the module needs to do with that `Collection`. If nobody else needs to know about it then sure, keep it local-scope.

*Do consider* making it the caller's responsibility to provide the collection as an argument - making it the caller's concern to know how many times it's invoking that procedure.

```
Public Sub TestParameter(ByRef items As VBA.Collection)
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Set items = New VBA.Collection
    End If
    With items
        .Add "entry" & .Count + 1
        Debug.Print .Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed explanations and for providing code.

Comment: If the collection had an initial value (at the first call), I am guessing the [If items Is Nothing Then] clause should also include the initialization part as well.

Comment: @Barok you could have that with `Private myCollection As New VBA.Collection`. Beware though, `As New` declarations can have unintended consequences: you can't `Set` them to `Nothing` and then reference them in a `If ... Is Nothing` check, because that reference will automatically recreate the instance, and the condition will always evaluate to `True`... better avoid `As New` declarations.

Comment: I would like to put collections within Public Subs such as TestStaticVariable() rather using global collections such as Private myCollection As New VBA.Collection due to error handling hassles. Would including initial values within [If items Is Nothing Then] clause cause any unforeseen problems? What happens when an exception occurs? Will the static collection die?

Comment: The `If items Is Nothing Then` block is exactly where you add whatever initial values need to be there, yes. Note that module-scope "Private" variables aren't "global", they're only accessible within the module they're declared in. When an error occurs you need to handle it, if an error bubbles all the way up the call stack then your program (and its state) is essentially toast.